# Display react component name in attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

While working with React, i would like to display component name in an attribute of the component. E.g. if I have a component `<LoginBox />` I would like it to be rendered as

```html
<div data-react-name="LoginBox">...</div>
```

But I want this to be done automatically for each transpiled component. Reason for this is automated testing when I'd check for rendered elements in HTML/DOM, currently a component is not differentiated by the name in rendered HTML.

I thought I'd write a babel plugin, but I have no idea what visitors I'd use and how to make it robust enough. I tried google for such a plugin but I have no idea how it would be called and found nothing useful.

So is there any plugin or any way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use React developer tools, in React tab, the DOM structure shows names of components, if you want only for testing.

Comment: I want it for automted testing. I've updated the post.

Comment: What tools are you using for automated testing?

Comment: Cucumber, selenium. But that should not make a difference. Or does it?

Comment: @MáriusRak  did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @DaveClissold, no, I've started adding custom attributes such as data-testname. They can be eventually removed by babel in production.

Comment: @MáriusRak ok thanks, bit of a shame, for us that is not feasable.  

I am trying to work on a custom babel plugin, but am getting duplication across all the html elements within a component, eg every <div> in a file, which is unnecessary duplication.  If I can find a way of just getting the first JSXElement within Babel I will have something working I can share with you, but it seems nobody has ever tried to get the first X in BabelJS

Comment: @DaveClissold, well, I've found a solution. See the answer :)

Comment: I found one as well a bit later on in the day.  Am waiting for the ok from the boss to open source it, had to take several different plugin concepts and merge them for my needs.  Traversing through straight to the JSXOpeningElement is great, but I found a lot of duplication appearing in nested div's and wrapper / container divs, just the nature of our dev teams code and styling practices.  I also had to catch.

`export default function() {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now after a year, as I'm rethinking, it should be quite easy.
For more details on writing plugins see [handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md).
Use [ASTexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/) to inspect what AST would your code result in. And then, for generated tree, prepare visitors. So e.g. with code:

```
<div><Custom some-prop="prop">Some text</Custom></div>
```

we would infer, that we need to use visitor `JSXOpeningElement` and alter `node`'s property `attribute`. To this property - array we would add a new element that we would create by [`Babel.types.jsxAttribute(name, value)`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#jsxattribute). We will get the name of tag from `node`'s property `.name.name` (the `name` string is nested inside `name` object). We also need to use appropriate types. So it would look like this:

```js
module.exports =  function(Babel) {
        return {
                visitor: {
                        JSXOpeningElement(path) {
                                const name = Babel.types.jsxIdentifier('data-testname');
                                const value = Babel.types.stringLiteral(path.node.name.name);
                                path.node.attributes.push(Babel.types.jsxAttribute(name, value));
                        }
                }
        };
};
```

The code is tested with the [ASTExplorer](https://astexplorer.net/).